# Vpn connection succeeds from machine #A but fails from machine #B

Tags: dns, openvpn

In these dark times, while (due to coronavirus) having (like many people) to do some home office, I have to connect to the VPN of my company.
The latter configured my laptop #A (ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS) with openvpn so that I have access to the VPN, and it works correctly.

I then tried to configure myself a second more powerful laptop (laptop #B, ubuntu 19.10) by installing openvpn (same version: 2.4.8 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), and by copying :

- the configuration file (myConfig.ovpn)
- the P12 file containing my
  user id (MyUserId.p12)
- the TLS encryption key file
  (myEncryptionKey.key)
- the file containing my identifiers (auth.txt)
- the CA certificate from my company (my_company_ca.crt)

but, despite a message saying on my machine #B that the connection sequence has completed, the whole log is shorter (some messages about dhcp-option are missing), and I cannot connect tu my company servers with it.
 It looks like some DNS config issues, but I'm not sure.

How can I fix that ?

Here are my logs on laptop #A (succesful connection) :

```
Fri Mar 13 09:11:22 2020 WARNING: file 'MyUserId.p12' is group or others accessible
Fri Mar 13 09:11:22 2020 WARNING: file 'myEncryptionKey.key' is group or others accessible
Fri Mar 13 09:11:22 2020 WARNING: file 'auth.txt' is group or others accessible
Fri Mar 13 09:11:22 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.8 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Oct 31 2019
Fri Mar 13 09:11:22 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Fri Mar 13 09:11:22 2020 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Fri Mar 13 09:11:23 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 09:11:23 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194 [nonblock]
Fri Mar 13 09:11:24 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 09:11:24 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Mar 13 09:11:24 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 09:11:24 2020 [my.company.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 09:11:31 2020 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: block-outside-dns (2.4.8)
Fri Mar 13 09:11:31 2020 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: register-dns (2.4.8)
Fri Mar 13 09:11:31 2020 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Mar 13 09:11:31 2020 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri Mar 13 09:11:31 2020 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 ccc.dd.2.116/23 broadcast ccc.dd.3.255
Fri Mar 13 09:11:31 2020 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1555 ccc.dd.2.116 255.255.254.0 init
dhcp-option DOMAIN pfa.tds
dhcp-option DNS xx.yy.zzz.93
dhcp-option DNS xx.yy.zzz.94
dhcp-option DOMAIN my.company.com
dhcp-option DOMAIN company.local
dhcp-option DOMAIN bla.foo.doh
Fri Mar 13 09:11:33 2020 Initialization Sequence Complete
```

And my logs on laptop #B (failing connection) :

```
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 WARNING: file 'MyUserId.p12' is group or others accessible
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 WARNING: file 'myEncryptionKey.key' is group or others accessible
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 WARNING: file 'auth.txt' is group or others accessible
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.8 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Oct 30 2019
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019, LZO 2.10
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 NOTE: the current --script-security setting may allow this configuration to call user-defined scripts
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 18:56:56 2020 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194 [nonblock]
Fri Mar 13 18:56:57 2020 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 18:56:57 2020 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
Fri Mar 13 18:56:57 2020 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 18:56:58 2020 [my.company.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]aaa.bb.94.187:1194
Fri Mar 13 18:57:00 2020 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: block-outside-dns (2.4.8)
Fri Mar 13 18:57:00 2020 Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:5: register-dns (2.4.8)
Fri Mar 13 18:57:00 2020 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Fri Mar 13 18:57:00 2020 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Fri Mar 13 18:57:00 2020 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 ccc.dd.2.116/23 broadcast ccc.dd.3.255
Fri Mar 13 18:57:00 2020 /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf tun0 1500 1555 ccc.dd.2.116 255.255.254.0 init
Fri Mar 13 18:57:00 2020 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

And Here is my ovpn config file:

```
dev tun
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-128-CBC
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM:AES-256-GCM
auth SHA256
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote my.company.com 1194 tcp-client
verify-x509-name "my.company.com" name
auth-user-pass auth.txt
ca my_company_ca.crt
pkcs12 MyUserId.p12
tls-crypt myEncryptionKey.key
comp-lzo adaptive
auth-nocache
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-con
```

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of Ubuntu will use a newer package version of OpenVPN.  The move from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 would brake the OpenVPN connection to the server because the default encryption is higher and required now.  This could be your issue possibly.  `openvpn --version` yields the same version on both laptops?

Also, do not try to connect to the server from both clients using the same keys at the same time, it will cause issues.